# How to make so slider show up just in home page and anywhere else

Tags: php, wordpress, customization

[PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SU9L.jpg)I have short code `<?php echo do_shortcode('[wonderplugin_slider id=1]'); ?>` and have to put it above the page see in the picture

The issue is the slider (shortcode)  should display **JUST** on Homepage or Main page.

I have  tried many plugins and codes like this `<?php if(is_page(<111>)) { ?><?php }>`but it does not work

Comment: Is your homepage standard WP page with posts, or some static page?

Comment: I use woo commerce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `is_front_page()`, `is_home()` and `is_page()` functions.

In your code, you want to mention the page id directly means please put it without any quotes like below.

```
<?php 
if(is_page(111)){
   echo do_shortcode('[wonderplugin_slider id=1]');
}
?>
```

Or else you already set the page with id `111` as the home page or front page means, you can use `is_home()` and `is_front_page()` function.

```
if( is_front_page() ) { 
   echo do_shortcode('[wonderplugin_slider id=1]');
}
```

or

```
if( is_front_page() && is_home() ) { 
 echo do_shortcode('[wonderplugin_slider id=1]');
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks bro say what I can do for you for your help?

Comment: Nice catch about page id, didn't notice that and that's why voting your answer up, but still your 3rd option woln't work with static front page and that's worth mentioning

Answer (score 0):

You shpuld check both [is_home()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/) and [is_front_page()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page), but their usage depends on the frontpage you have. If you have a statick frontpage you can have:

```
 if( is_front_page() ) { 
   ...
 }
```

In the other way around you can conbine both like:

```
 if( is_front_page() && is_home() ) { 
 ...
 }
```